# WCF stream response returning garbage characters

Tags: wcf, encoding, stream

**Hello guys,**
i have a web service **returning XML response as a stream**, it's a string that later i convert into memory stream before returning it as a response. The problem is, string has some chinese characters which work fine if my return type of service is plain string, but they show **garbage characters** if i convert them into stream and then choose stream as my return type.

```
Stream strmResponse = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlstringResponse));
```

above code is converting all the chinese characters into garbage characters and this is the response i get. changing encoding into ASCII will simply replace chinese characters with **"??"**

```
<data contentType="application/octet-stream" contentLength="1808"><![CDATA[<MESSAGE_BODY><RESPONSE><RESULT>æˆ�åŠŸ</RESULT></RESPONSE></MESSAGE_BODY>]]></data>
```

however the **correct chinese is "成功"** which means Success. Below is the signature of my method

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "SendDCFileResponse", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
[OperationContract]
Stream SendDCFileResponse(Stream xmlParam);
```

**changing return type to "string" will make things working** but **using stream is the requirement** for me. I have checked my binding and it's basicHttpBinding which means it supports UTF8 by default, still i have explictly specified UTF-8 as content type but there is no luck. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I tried webhttpbinding and basichttpbinding but did not encounter the problem you said:

**webhttpbinding**

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "SendDCFileResponse", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
        [OperationContract]
        Stream SendDCFileResponse(Stream xmlParam);

 public Stream SendDCFileResponse(Stream xmlParam)
        {
            string xmlstringResponse = " < data contentType = \"application/octet-stream\" contentLength = \"1808\" >< ![CDATA[< MESSAGE_BODY >< RESPONSE >< RESULT >成功</ RESULT ></ RESPONSE ></ MESSAGE_BODY >]] ></ data >";
            Stream strmResponse = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlstringResponse));
            return strmResponse;
        }
```

[image]

**basichttpbinding**

```
[OperationContract]
Stream SendDCFileResponse(Stream xmlParam);

 public Stream SendDCFileResponse(Stream xmlParam)
        {
            string xmlstringResponse =" < data contentType = \"application/octet-stream\" contentLength = \"1808\" >< ![CDATA[< MESSAGE_BODY >< RESPONSE >< RESULT >成功</ RESULT ></ RESPONSE ></ MESSAGE_BODY >]] ></ data >";
            Stream strmResponse = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlstringResponse));
            return strmResponse;
        }
```

[image]

Feel free to let me know if the problem persists.

Comment: Please point out if your project is different from the one I created.